# How to show a value of a Cell as it's displayed

Tags: spreadsheet, conditional-formatting

I have a cell A2 that shows the value 001.  I want to concatenate that value of 001 to a string to show REQ-001.  The cell that I want to show this string I have =CONCATENATE("REQ-",A3).  But the results show REQ-1, and not REQ-001.  For Cell A2 I have it as Custom 000

Comment: Why does your formula refer to A3 if the value you want is in A2? Using text formatting, this works just fine for me, resulting in `REQ-001`. Have you tried to format the cell/column as text?

Comment: What kind of spreadsheet are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`=CONCATENATE("REQ-",TEXT(A3,"000"))`

Formating the value to 000 and making it text.